# Searching App to Upgrade Android Text Selection

Tags: copy-paste

I'm reaching out to see if you might have a lead on a specific type of Android app I've been searching for. It's all about making text copying and pasting more efficient on my device, especially for tasks where I need to switch between different text sets.

Here's What I'm After:

An app that enhances the regular text selection bubbles (those menus that pop up when you highlight text) with some neat clipboard features.

Ideally, it would let me quickly access a list of my recently copied items, or some favorite phrases, right in those selection bubbles.

The key is integration – I'm hoping for something that blends seamlessly with the existing text selection process, without the need to switch screens or go through extra steps.

What I've Seen So Far: I've come across various clipboard manager apps, but they don't quite hit the mark. Most of them operate through notifications or separate interfaces, which isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Why This Matters to Me: Getting this functionality right would seriously streamline my workflow. I often find myself needing to copy and paste different text segments, and this could make the whole process a lot smoother.

If anyone knows of an app that fits this description or has any suggestions, I'd really appreciate your input. And if there's nothing out there like this yet, maybe this could be an interesting project for any developers in this community?

Thanks so much in advance for your help and advice!

Edit: On another forum Texpand was suggested and it fits my needs, so if anyone needs someone similar here you go. But if there are alternatives feel free to add ideas.